Python Turtle - onclick() handler not working when defined in class
Having a bit of trouble getting onclick handlers in Python Turtle to work properly. I have the following class in its own file:
from typing import Tuple
from turtle import Turtle

class Card:
    
    def __init__(self, val: int, img: str, location: Tuple[float, float],
                 back: str = "card_back.gif"):
        self.value = val
        self.front = img
        self.back = back
        self.location = location
        self.turtle = Turtle()
        
        self.is_face_down = True
        
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(self.location)
        self.turtle.onclick(self.flip)
        self.turtle.showturtle()
        
    def show_back(self):
        self.turtle.shape(self.back)
        self.is_face_down = True
        
    def show_front(self):
        self.turtle.shape(self.front)
        self.is_face_down = False
        
    def flip(self, x, y):
        if self.is_face_down:
            self.show_front()
        else:
            self.show_back()

However, when I create an instance in a separate file, the onclick handler does not work. What does work is if I define the onclick from outside, like so:
...
    two_club1 = Card(0, "2_of_clubs.gif", (-400, 250))
    
    two_club1.show_back()
    two_club1.turtle.onclick(two_club1.flip) # Without this, the click does not work
    
    turtle.done()

Why can I not define the onclick handler in the class itself? To my knowledge, I should be able to define it in __init__ and it should work. Is it because I'm importing the class into another file?

Your Card class works fine for me, so I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Can you provide a [mcve]? I should be able to copy-paste the file, run it and see the problem--multiple files likely aren't necessary. BTW, kudos on using composition, not inheritance with your Card class. Thanks,
